# Install python libraries on all openshift pods

Tags: ssh, openshift, redash

I have a redash server deployed on an on premise openshift cluster, with about 20 pods.
I want to install new python libraries on the server and I'm able to ssh to one of the pods using `oc rsh` and run `pip install x`.

The problem is that I have a lot of pods and don't want to ssh to each pods when I need a new library.
I also don't want to change the image and have to redeploy my server every time.
Is there a way to run a command on all pods at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to do Pod maintenance using `oc rsh`. The right way to go here would be to **update the container image and redeploy your application**, that is how Kubernetes / OpenShift works.

For example, when one of your Pods is restarted for any reason (the underlying Node has an issue, your application crashes, an administrator deletes a Pod, ...) then your change will be gone as the Pod is restarted.

Usually, container images are built via a pipeline or similar, so re-building an image should not be an issue. That being said, a hacky way to run a command in all Pods is the following:

```
for pod in $(oc get pods -o name); do
  oc rsh $pod pip install x
done
```